# how can i print to a specific printer using win.webContents.print()

Tags: node.js, electron

How can I print to a specific printer using `win.webContents.print()` in electron? i couldn't find an option for that. Only `silent` and `printBackground` options are there.

Can any suggest a solution for this? any help will be appreciated.